# ionic3 angular4: How to make only checkbox clickable not whole row?

Tags: javascript, ionic3, angular4-forms

Here is the context:

I have a list of rows.
In that row I want to click only checkbox but I am unable to do that.
I also have an array of rows which holds three value name as numbers, value as strings, and checked value as true.

My HTML code is here:

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let row of rows;let idx:index">
      <ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [name]="row.name" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="row.checked"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [name]="row.name" [(ngModel)]="row.value"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

in my .ts file I had written this:

```
this.rows.push({ name: 1, value: '',checked:true });
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is when I click on checkbox I just to select that particular checkbox not entire row.